# For Each, set element's title to some string

Tags: 8, entities, forms

Hi I have made a custom module to alter the address module form. It works well for one field, however I am stuck trying to use a for each loop in recursively calling this to as many elements there are.

My current code is as such:

```
function address_custom_address($element, $form_state) {
  $element[0]['address']['given_name']['#title'] = t('Base Name');
  $element[1]['address']['given_name']['#title'] = t('Base Name');
  $element[2]['address']['given_name']['#title'] = t('Base Name'); 
  return $element;
}
```

this works, however as you can tell it is redundant and does not satify cases in which the user creates more than 3+ addresses.

I tried to use a foreach loop

```
foreach($element as $value){
   $title = $value['address']['given_name']['#title']; //this is the title of each element
   //assert title not null
   if(isset($title)) {

      //this is the error it gives me
      $value['address']['given_name'] = array(
       '#title' => 'Base Name',
     );
   }
}
```

Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

If anyone has references to where i can better understand this, that would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but doing it slightly incorrect. You can use this:

```
function address_custom_address($element, $form_state) {
  $i = 0;
  while (isset($element[$i)) {
    $element[$i]['address']['given_name']['#title'] = t('Base Name');

    $i++;
  }

  return $element;
}
```

Comment: That worked! I didn't think of doing a while loop, wow. Thanks a lot.